# Handling bulk insert on a table with multiple input sources in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am  performing  bulk insert on a table in sql server 2012, at the same time i am picking the last inserted row with max() function and inserting it into another table , how to perform this when my table is getting data from multiple sources   because while performing insertion into secondary table there is time delay while insertions are still happening in primary table so next time max() will pick up last updated row and i will loose some rows which are not max() but still inserted into primary table meanwhile.

```
create table dbo.emp
(
id int primary key identity(1,1),
emp_id int,
name varchar(255),
address varchar(255)
)

create table dbo.empx
(
id int primary key,
emp_id int foreign key references dbo.emp(id),
)


    declare @temp int ;
        set @temp=1;
        while @temp<1000
        begin
        insert into dbo.emp(emp_id,name,address)values (100+@temp,'Ename'+LTRIM(STR(@temp)),'123 Sample Address'+LTRIM(STR(@temp)));
        set @temp=@temp+1; 

        insert into dbo.empx  select max(dbo.emp.id),max(dbo.emp.emp_id) from dbo.emp 

        end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use OUTPUT Clause...

```
CREATE TABLE #empx
(Id INT ,emp_id VARCHAR(50))

DECLARE @temp INT ;
SET @temp=1;
    WHILE @temp<1000
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO dbo.emp(emp_id,name,address)
            OUTPUT INSERTED.Id,INSERTED.emp_id INTO #empx(Id,emp_id)
        VALUES (100+@temp,'Ename'+LTRIM(STR(@temp)),'123 Sample Address'+LTRIM(STR(@temp)));

        SET @temp=@temp+1; 

    END
INSERT INTO dbo.empx(Id,emp_id)
SELECT Id,emp_id FROM #empx
```

Or Use a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER EmpLog
   ON  dbo.emp
   AFTER Insert
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Insert into dbo.empx (id,emp_id) Select id,emp_id from inserted;
END
GO
```

Comment: output clause dosen't allow foreign key references, in my case  tables are create table dbo.emp
(
id int primary key identity(1,1),
emp_id int,
name varchar(255),
address varchar(255)
)

create table dbo.empx
(
id int primary key,
emp_id int foreign key references dbo.emp(id),
)

Comment: My first thought was to use a trigger but  trigger will be invoked on each insert(consider 4lac insertions) isn't it that an insert query will be  much lighter than invoking a trigger .

Comment: Ok then you can output the data into temp table first and after that you can load it to original.. i have modified first set of script.. please check..

Comment: Yeah that's the solution i was looking for it  solved my issue Thank You so much :)

Comment: You are always welcome.. :) by the way give an upvote also.. that will increase my points .. ;)

Comment: I upvoted your answer but it will be reflected here when it will have more than 15 upvotes.

Comment: please provide some insights to this problem http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/150043/how-to-synchronize-multiple-instances-of-a-stored-procedure-executing-at-the-sam